# iOS: Failed to launch .app file

Tags: iphone, ios5.1, launching-application, .app

I don't know why it is looking for directory inside my .app file. Every time I run application it installs the App on iPhone but doesn't run and gives below error. Could anyone please tell me where's this settings stored? Thanks.

```
error: failed to launch '/Users/xxx/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp- ccbvvzjjzvwuerchrpulknxtenoq/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/MyApp.app/MyApp' -- No such file or directory (/Users/xxx/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-ccbvvzjjzvwuerchrpulknxtenoq/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/MyApp.app/MyApp)
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Try with:
  1 - remove the app from the iPhone.
  2 - remove the contents of the `DerivedData` folder.
  3 - Clean & Build the project, restart Xcode, and reboot your device.

**EDIT:**
Now for the step 2 in Xcode 5 you can delete the derived data from the Organizer, just select the `Projects` tab, select you project and click the "Delete…" button on the right.

Comment: that's strange!! I restarted Xcode and clean the project. It worked! Thanks.

Comment: Same here, restarting Xcode was the missing operation. Now it works again!

Answer (score 12):

If, like me, you see this error in XCODE 6 : ***“process launch failed: NotFound"***

I finally find that the "not found" thing is about the device itself. It was well recognised in the Organizer and everything was working before but xcode didn't managed to run the app on it.

What worked for me : simply **try to reboot your device** and voila :)

Too bad XCODE still has such unclear error messages! A little more details could spare a lot of hours...

Comment: helped me! i love these errors.. it really makes developing for the iphone a mental challenge! that's what i love about coding :) (NOT)

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem. I tried with restarting the Xcode and deleting the app form device and it worked.
Before trying anything complex try this It should work for you also.

Answer (score 2):

Whenever I get the message "Failed to launch .app file", I always check my code signing settings... It usually occurs when I forget to change my code signing identity back to developer from distribution

Comment: I am using developer cert only. If you use distribution cert and try to run, it says "Cannot find process xxx" not failed to launch!

Answer (score 0):

For me restarting of Xcode, cleaning DerivedData and restaring device wasn't enough in most cases, until I had figured out that iTunes was also running, and after quitting iTunes everything worked fine!

So my steps now are simple:

**1. Quit Xcode.**
**2. If iTunes is running, quit iTunes.**
**3. Reopen project.**

No need to remove app, clean project or restart device.

Answer (score 0):

I cleaned out my provisional profiles, rebooted the iPhone, and rebooted the computer, and it worked for me.