# Application/Launch icon doesn't appear in iPhone 5.0 simulator or device

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ios5

I think I have done everything to set up my app launch icon correctly but it doesn't seem to be working in the iPhone 5 simulator or device.  I have verified it works in the 4.3 simulator and device.  Here is everything that I have set:

In the root of the project, I've got both the 57x57 and 114x114 images added:

[image: added to project]

These also show up in the info.plist:

[image: info.plist]

And they show up in the summary view:

[image: summary view]

When I run this with the 4.3 simulator it works for both normal and retina resolutions:

[image: 4.3normal]

[image: 4.3retina]

However, when I run them with the 5.0 simulator the icon doesn't show for either the normal or retina resolutions:

[image: 5.0normal]

[image: 5.0retina]

I've tried resaving and renaming the images along with unsetting and resetting all of the properties in the project with no luck.  I've also confirmed that this isn't just a simulator problem.  When I load the application onto the iPhone 5, it has the same issue when it works on the iPhone 4.  I haven't been able to try it on the 4S but I imagine it would have the same issue.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried cleaning the bundle?

Comment: 1. What max_ said. 2. Icon.png and Icon@2x.png. 3. Try "reset content and settings" in the simulator.

Comment: Try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10833382/251513); is not the same case, but it should works.

Comment: Yeah, like NSPost said, icons are usually named icon.png and icon@2x.png

Comment: Delete the app and reinstall.

Comment: Yep, I had tried cleaning the bundle and the resent content and settings (along with deleting the app and reinstalling) but none of those things worked.  Renaming to Icon.png and Icon@2x.png fixed the issue!  It's pretty lame that having different names broke with the iPhone 5.0 SDK but I'll take the fix.  @NSPostWhenIdle, if you want to make your comment into an answer, I'll gladly mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Traditionally](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/App-RelatedResources/App-RelatedResources.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH6-SW1) icons for iPhone applications are named `Icon.png` and `Icon@2x.png`.

> - Icon.png. The name for the app icon on iPhone or iPod touch.
> - Icon-72.png. The name for the app icon on iPad.
> - Icon-Small.png. The name for the search results icon on iPhone and    iPod touch. This file is also used for the Settings icon on all
>   devices.
> - Icon-Small-50.png. The name of the search results icon on iPad.

Additionally, similar problems can usually be solved by cleaning all targets in your project using "command-shift-k" or "command-option-shift-k".